# Linux libc++ seems to be broken

Tags: linux, installation, debian, discord, libc++

Hay all!

Today, i installed the deepin distro (based on debian) on my laptop.
When trying to install Discord, it mentioned that the dependency libc++ was broken or impossible.

When trying to install, the problem output was:

```
libc6 is already the newest version (2.27-3).
libc6-dev is already the newest version (2.27-3).
libc6-dev-amd64:i386 is already the newest version (2.27-3).
libc6-udeb is already the newest version (2.19-18+deb8u10).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6:i386 : Conflicts: libc6-i686:i386
 libc6-dev-amd64:i386 : Depends: libc6-amd64:i386 (= 2.27-3) but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: gcc-multilib:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I used this command to install:

```
sudo apt install libc++6
```

I am running a 64x system, and did not manage to fix it.
Does any one have a suggestion for how to fix it or know what im doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you're showing us the wrong things.  What we probably need to see is the exact error message you got when you tried to install Discord.

Comment: The discord installer itself did not give an error. It refused to install the deb package due to the broken dependency. All it says is "broken dependencies: libc++1" and then closes

Comment: I think libc++6 is being treated as a regex, and that's why you're seeing that stuff related to libc6

Comment: Oh my gosh that was indeed it, a manual install from file indeed worked, thank you both for your time <3

Comment: @MatsMoolhuizen - please don't edit questions to add things like "solved" - that's what answers are for. I rolled back your edit, accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED!

by installing it manualy from: https://debian.pkgs.org/8/debian-main-amd64/libc++1_3.5-2_amd64.deb.html

as @EricWF pointed out, libc++ gets detected as a regex